# Does using regular div tags instead of table and related tags affect accessibility?

Tags: html, css, html-table, accessibility

I have a table which should show a typical table layout on larger screens and should become a column view on smaller screens. For example.

Desktop

```
| Name  | age |
| Bob   | 48  |
| Jane  | 50  |
```

Mobile (The  below show up as a list)

```
--------
Name:Bob,
Age: 48
-------
Name:Jane,
Age: 50
```

Would using regular `div` tags instead of the usual `table` mark up cause issues for accessibility?

The reason why I do not prefer the usual `table` markup is because it isn't flexible for complex UIs. For example if you want to add add a margin after each row you have to manipulate  `border-collapse` `border-spacing` and do a whole bunch of other things.

My question is. Does using regular `divs` with grid/flex properties cause accessibility issues ? If yes how can we overcome it? Is there a way to make the screen reader interpret the `divs` as `table` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using divs to mark up tabular information will cause accessibility issues. Assistive technologies can easily parse tables and provide users easy and consistent ways for navigating that information. Divs have no semantic meaning that assistive tech can parse—unless you carefully add appropriate [`aria-role` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques).

Tables can be responsively styled to fit the layout changes you describe. My recommendation would be to use table elements and style them differently with media queries at smaller widths.

**Table styled as a table:**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: 1ch;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-heading="Name">Bob</td>
    <td data-heading="Age">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-heading="Name">Jane</td>
    <td data-heading="Age">50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Same accessible table markup styled as a list:**

```css
table,
tbody,
tr,
td {
  display: block;
}
tr:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1ch;
}
td:before {
  content: attr(data-heading) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-heading="Name">Bob</td>
    <td data-heading="Age">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-heading="Name">Jane</td>
    <td data-heading="Age">50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's some nifty CSS to style a table as a list (visually). When navigating both tables with a screen reader, they read slightly different. You don't get the normal column header announcement with the second/list example. You **can** use `<div>` elements to create a table, but as @sean noted at the beginning of his answer, you must add appropriate roles to all the elements.  You'll need roles of `table`, `row`, `cell`, `columnheader`, and `rowheader`. You can have great flexibility of layout doing it this way. Adding the roles in the right places just takes patience.

Comment: @slugolicious I wasn't aware there was a difference in how they're both presented by screen readers. I wonder if that's reader specific. Will do some more testing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you remove the table structure then a screen reader can't present that structure to the user.

Comment: Is there a way to make the screen reader interpret the divs as table elements ?

Comment: This MDN article might help here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_Layout_and_Accessibility

Comment: A grid layout does **not** have table semantics and screen readers will not report it as having tabular relationships.

Comment: It depends on how you use the term "grid". As referenced in the mozilla article, a grid is used for layout purposes and I agree that a layout grid is **not** conveyed to screen reader users as a table.  However, there is a `role="grid"` that **is** conveyed as a table to screen reader users

Comment: Aren't table semantics, for a div table, solved by just having well-placed aria-roles? Or it there something that classic `<table>`'s still provide that div-table-with-proper-aria-roles doesn't offer?